How to store an array and a slice of that array in a struct in Rust?
I have a struct to save data read from a socket connection. This struct has an array field buffer which provides space for the read data to be saved in. Now, I need to way to save which part of that buffer contains actual data. For example, if my buffer is 1024 bytes in size, but I only read 100 bytes from the connection, I'd like to have a reference to only that 100 bytes. So I thought I'm gonna do something like this:
struct MyStruct {
    buffer: [u8; 1024],
    current_data: &[u8]
}

However Rust needs to know the lifetime of the object referenced by current_data. Unfortunately, Rust is currently missing a way to tell the compiler that current_data is just a reference to another field of the struct and not something outside of it. So I have to use lifetime specifiers like this:
struct MyStruct<'a> {
    buffer: [u8; 1024],
    current_data: &'a [u8]
}

But now my problem is how to construct that struct. I can't one-line it like this:
pub fn new() -> Self {
    Self {
        buffer: [0; BUF_SIZE],
        pointer: &buffer
    }
}

because there's no variable named buffer at the point I'm constructing this struct. So I guess I have to create the buffer first, and then I can borrow it. But if I create the buffer outside of the struct, it's a temporary value and I can't borrow it. And if I first assign a placeholder value like &[] to current_data, and then afterwards let it reference buffer, like this:
pub fn new() -> Self {
        let mut obj = Self {
            buffer: [0; BUF_SIZE],
            pointer: &buffer
        };

        obj.pointer = &obj.buffer;

        obj
    }

then I can't return obj because it has been borrowed.
Is there any simple way I can solve this? Are you seeing any issues with the design of it?
If there's no good solution for this, that's okay, I'm just gonna not use a slice to save which part of the buffer holds important data, and instead just use two integers that hold the start and end of the section. I'd then have to always slice the buffer manually like self.buffer[self.start..self.end], which is why I wanted to know if I can hold this slice permanentaly in the struct, but if it's not possible I'm fine with it. I'm still learning rust.

This is a textbook self-referential struct which cannot be expressed properly with Rust's lifetimes. There are some third-party crates mentioned in the linked Q&A that can help out if you need references, but in some cases like yours using indexes is often the best alternative.

Note that, in your particular case, the compiler saved you from undefined behavior. As soon as you move obj (by returning it) the location of the buffer array can change, which potentially invalidates the reference in pointer.
